# Rails - Parameters not being saved when using nested forms in Cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I've followed Cocoon's instructions for creating a nested form for a has_many association but there's one thing that I can't seem to figure out. I'm able to add an existing genre to my project but when it comes to creating a completely new one the parameters for my genres aren't being permitted. When I refer to my rails console to debug the issue this is the message I receive upon update:

`Unpermitted parameters: genre_attributes`

What's strange is I've permitted both my join table `genreships` and my `genre` model along with having my `movie` model accept their nested attributes but still no luck. There has to be something I'm not doing in my `movie_params` method but not able to find what. I've literally tried to permit every possible attribute within this method and completely out of ideas on what could be the solution

**Models**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :genreships
    has_many :genres, through: :genreships

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :genres, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :genreships, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end

class Genreship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie
    belongs_to :genre

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :genre, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :genreships
    has_many :movies, through: :genreships

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

**Movies Controller**

```
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :release_date, :summary, genreships_attributes: [:id, :genre_id, :_destroy], genres_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :name])
end
```

**Form**

```
= simple_form_for @movie do |f|

  .field
    = f.input :title
  .field
    = f.input :release_date, label: 'Release Date', order: [:month, :day, :year], start_year: 1901
  .field
    = f.input :summary, as: :text
  #genres
    = f.simple_fields_for :genreships do |genreship|
      = render 'genreship_fields', :f => genreship
    = link_to_add_association 'add a genre', f, :genreships
  .actions = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-default'
```

**Genreship Partial**

```
.nested-fields
  #genre_from_list
    = f.association :genre, :collection => Genre.order(:name), :prompt => 'Choose an existing genre'
  = link_to_add_association 'or create a new genre', f, :genre
  = link_to_remove_association "remove genre", f
```

**Genre Partial**

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :name
```

**Here's what's shown in the rails console right after posting a new movie:**

```
Started POST "/movies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-19 08:17:42 -0500

Processing by MoviesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2/wqXhn/x73AdOOrSo49Q/OPAmrcVk0rLViJJNpIhps=", "movie"=>{"title"=>"", "release_date(2i)"=>"11", "release_date(3i)"=>"19", "release_date(1i)"=>"2014", "summary"=>"", "genreships_attributes"=>{"1416403056574"=>{"genre_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Comedy"}, "genre_id"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
Unpermitted parameters: genre_attributes
```

Comment: At first sight this is exactly how I do it in my [demo-project](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo) so afaik this should work. Mmmm can you show us what is posted to the controller?

Comment: @nathanvda Updated my question to show what's going on in my console. Let me know if anything else is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution that in a sense deviates from Nathan's example code somewhat but gets the job done nonetheless. Simply moving this line from `genreship_fields.html.slim` to `_form.html.slim` did the trick:

```
link_to_add_association 'create a new genre', f, :genres
```

My partials now look like this:

**Form**

```
= simple_form_for @movie do |f|
  .field
    = f.input :title
  .field
    = f.input :release_date, label: 'Release Date', order: [:month, :day, :year], start_year: 1901
  .field
    = f.input :summary, as: :text
  #genres
    = f.simple_fields_for :genreships do |genreship|
      = render 'genreship_fields', :f => genreship
    | #{link_to_add_association 'add a genre', f, :genreships} | #{link_to_add_association 'create a new genre', f, :genres}
  .actions = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-default'
```

**Genreship Partial**

```
.nested-fields
  #genre_from_list
    = f.association :genre, :collection => Genre.order(:name), :prompt => 'Choose an existing genre'
  = link_to_remove_association "remove genre", f
```

**Genre Partial**

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :name
  = link_to_remove_association "remove form", f
```

Comment: Nice you found a working solution.What I could tell from your posted parameters, is that I would expect your strong_parameters declaration to have to be nested, but that is weird, since it is not needed in my example project. I haven't looked at it further.

Answer (score 0):

You use `genre_attributes` while `genres_attributes` (plural form) is defined in your controller. Change it to:

```
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :release_date, :summary, genreships_attributes: [:id, :genre_id, :_destroy], genre_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :name])
end
```

Comment: Still showing that its unpermitted despite the name change