# Using jQuery Tokeninput within a nested form partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials, jquery-tokeninput, cocoon-gem

I'm using jQuery Tokeninput as shown in this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields). I'd like to combine this functionality in a nested form but get the error

```
undefined method `artists' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x007febe0883988>
```

For some reason its not recognizing the track parameter in my form builder which is stopping me to get a hold of albums I have on record.

```
<div class="input">
  <%= f.input :artist_tokens, label: 'Featured Artists', input_html: {"data-pre" => f.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json} %>
</div>
```

Keep in mind this works in my `track` form but just not in my `album` form since its nested. What should I do to get this to work?

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @artists = Artist.order(:name)
      respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json {render json: @artists.tokens(params[:q])}
      end
    end
end
```

**Models**

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :album_ownerships
    has_many :albums, through: :album_ownerships

    has_many :featured_artists
    has_many :tracks, through: :featured_artists


    def self.tokens(query)
      artists = where("name like ?", "%#{query}%")

      if artists.empty?
        [{id: "<<<#{query}>>>", name: "Add New Artist: \"#{query}\""}]
      else
        artists
      end
    end

    def self.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
      tokens.gsub!(/<<<(.+?)>>>/) {create!(name: $1).id}
      tokens.split(',')
    end
end

class Albums < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_reader :artist_tokens

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

    has_many :albums_ownerships
    has_many :artists, through: :albums_ownerships

    def artist_tokens=(ids)
        self.artist_ids = Artist.ids_from_tokens(ids)
    end
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_reader :artist_tokens

    belongs_to :album

    has_many :featured_artists
    has_many :artists, through: :featured_artists

    def artist_tokens=(ids)
        self.artist_ids = Artist.ids_from_tokens(ids)
    end
end


class AlbumOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :artist
    belongs_to :album
end

class FeaturedArtist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :artist
    belongs_to :track
end
```

**Album Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@album) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <h1>Tracks</h1>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :tracks do |track| %>
    <%= render 'track_fields', :f => track %>
  <% end %>
  <div id='links'>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Field', f, :tracks %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Track Partial**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.input :name %><br>
</div>

<div class="input">
  <%= f.input :artist_tokens, label: 'Featured Artists', input_html: {"data-pre" => f.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json} %>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#track_artist_tokens').tokenInput('/artists.json', {
        prePopulate: $("#track_artist_tokens").data("pre"),
        theme: 'facebook',
        resultsLimit: 5
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by nathanvda, I needed to use `f.object` in order for the artists to be recognized. So in my partial I now have:

```
<%= f.input :artist_tokens, label: 'Featured Artists', input_html: {"data-pre" => f.object.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json, class: 'test_class'} %>
```

In my js I also needed to call the token input method before/after insertion:

```
$(function() {  
    $('.test_class').tokenInput('/artists.json', {
        prePopulate: $(".test_class").data("pre"),
        theme: 'facebook',
        resultsLimit: 5
    });


    $('form').bind('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, inserted_item) {
        inserted_item.find('.test_class').tokenInput('/artists.json', {
            prePopulate: $(".test_class").data("pre"),
            theme: 'facebook',
            resultsLimit: 5
        });
    });
});
```

The only remaining issue I have is the the `tracks_attributes` not being saved. I ran into an issue similar to this in the past in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996318/rails-parameters-not-being-saved-when-using-nested-forms-in-cocoon) but the two main difference is the second level of nesting involved and that I used a join table within my nested form. I'm not entirely sure if or how any of that code would translate over but I believe this is most likely problem. As far as the permitted params of my `albums_controller` here's what they looks like.

```
def album_params
  params.require(:album).permit(:name, :artist_tokens, tracks_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy, :track_id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to acces the object of a form, you need to write `f.object`, so I think you should just write `f.object.artists`.

Comment: Would you happen to know where I'd put this? Right now I have this in my `_track_fields` partial but get the error: `uninitialized constant Track::FeaturedArtist` with this code: `<%= f.input :artist_tokens, label: 'Featured Artists', input_html: {"data-pre" => f.object.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json} %>`

Comment: In your model you write that the artists are linked through featured artists, and that is the model that is not found. Can you check that track.artists works at all? You also have not shown use the definition for featured_artists.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I get the error: `undefined local variable or method 'track' for #<#<Class:0x007fdd978285f8>:0x007fdd97832d28>`. `FeaturedArtist` serves only as a join table between `artists` and `tracks`

Comment: Either you use a habtm which uses an implicit join table, or define the class `FeaturedArtist`. I would opt for the latter. Using the `f.object` solves your question imho. Please note that you can easily test your code using the rails console, so you can verify individual parts work (like retrieving the artists for a track).

Comment: Isn't `FeaturedArtist` already defined though? Would I need to add any additional code to what I already have besides the two associations: `belongs_to :artist` `belongs_to :track`. Everything seems to work fine in the console. Its the view code I'm having the worst time with.

Comment: So I returned to the code and re-implemented the input to look like this: `<%= f.input :artist_tokens, label: 'Featured Artists', input_html: {"data-pre" => f.object.artists.map(&:attributes).to_json, class: 'test_class'} %>`. No errors which is a good sign. The problem now is that the js is not being applied to the input for some reason. Here's the js:  `$('.test_class').tokenInput('/artists.json', {
  prePopulate: $(".test_class").data("pre"),
  theme: 'facebook',
  resultsLimit: 5
 });`

Comment: Not being applied to newly added nested items? Your jquery only is only applied when loading the page. Check the cocoon documentation regarding [callbacks](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items). If you have a problem with that, please ask a different question.

Comment: It looks like `f.object.artists` did the trick as well as implementing `cocoon:after-insert` in my js file. The one remaining problem I have is getting `tracks_fields` pass through as a permitted param. I had a similar issue with this in another post you were able to help me with but I believe this may be somewhat different because of the second level of nesting involved. I've updated my question to reflect my problem in more detail. Here's the link to the previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996318/rails-parameters-not-being-saved-when-using-nested-forms-in-cocoon

Comment: It is commonly not done to keep on expanding the question. Also you have not upvoted or accepted the answer, so I see no appreciation for my help. Normally questions tackle a specific issue, and when new problems arise, new questions are asked. But a quick tip: check what is posted to the controller and make sure your permitted params maps to the same structure. That being said, imho the `artists_tokens` should be inside the `track_attributes`.

Comment: That's never the case. You're help is always appreciated. I didn't know that additional problems would arise from the original question so my apologies if it appeared that I was expanding it. Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `"data-pre" => f.artists...` is calling the `artists` method on `f` which is the form builder and doesn't have an `#artists` method.

Try this instead:

In the album form, change the render partial line to this:

```
<%= render 'track_fields', :f => track, :artists => @artists %>
```

And then use this in the track partial:

```
<%= f.input :artist_tokens, label: 'Featured Artists', input_html: {"data-pre" => artists.map(&:attributes).to_json} %>
```

UPDATED

Let's back up a step. From your code it looks like you need to populate a `data-pre` attribute with the attributes of a collection of `artists`.

The problem is you're calling `f.artists` where `f` is the FormBuilder and doesn't know anything about `artists`. This is why you're getting `undefined method 'artists'...`

The solution is make a collection of artists available to the view and its partials. One way to do this:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @album = Album.new
    @artists = Artist.order(:name) # or some other subset of artists
  end

  ...

  def edit
    @album = Album.find params[:id]
    @artists = Artist.order(:name) # or perhaps "@artists = @album.artists", or some other subset of artists
  end
end
```

and then in `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb`, pass @artists to the form partial:

```
... # other view code
  <%= render 'form', album: @album %>
... # other view code
```

and then in your form partial:

```
... # other view code
<%= f.simple_fields_for :tracks do |track_form| %>
  <%= render 'track_fields', :f => track_form %>
<% end %>
... # other view code
```

finally, in your track partial:

```
... # other view code
<div class="input">
  <%= f.input :artist_tokens, label: 'Featured Artists', input_html: {"data-pre" => @artists.map(&:attributes).to_json} %>
</div>
... # other view code
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: With this I got: `undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: You showed the `index` action for the controller, but then some of your view code uses `@album`, which is not set in the `index` action. Is the problem in `new.html.erb` or `index.html.erb`? In either case, the corresponding controller action will need to set both `@artists`(like you did in the `index` action) and `@album`. If this doesn't help, can you post the controller action and corresponding view so I can take a look at both?

Comment: The problem is technically in my albums `_form.html.erb` which is rendered inside of my `new` and `edit` views. The reason I posted the artist's `new` action was to show how the json was retrieved for the jquery token functionality. I could post the rest of the controllers but none of the code was altered when they were generated via scaffold (not sure if that helps you or not). Are you recommending setting up an `@albums` variable in one of the controllers?

Comment: Still no luck. Despite creating those two instance variables its still complaining: `undefined local variable or method 'artists'` I created a repo to give you a better idea of what's going on. https://github.com/TKB21/nested_tokens

Comment: the problem occurs in `app/views/albums/new.html.erb`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65982/discussion-between-john-and-carl-edwards).